# How to add an item in a list using the java file chooser

Tags: java, list, jfilechooser

I am using the java file chooser in order to select a file from my local disk and output its name and path. Is there any way that I could select a file and add it to a list? Here is my code for the file chooser.

```
JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
File F = new File("C:/");
File namedir;
File namepath;    
chooser.setCurrentDirectory(F);
chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
chooser.setDialogTitle("Choose file ");
chooser.setApproveButtonText("View details");
namedir = chooser.getCurrentDirectory();
namepath = chooser.getSelectedFile();

JTextArea textarea = new JTextArea();
textarea.setEditable(false);
frame.add(textarea);

textarea.append("FILE LOCATION AND NAME:"+namepath);
System.out.print("the name of the the directory is "+namedir.getName());
System.out.print("the name of the the path is "+namepath.getAbsolutePath());
```

Comment: Are you trying to add the file object or the contents of the file to a list?

Comment: What I want is to create a playlist with songs that the user can select from the local disk. So basically I need to allow the user to put in a playlist mp3 files

Comment: I guess I don't see you can't use `List<File> playlistFiles = new ArrayList<>();  playListFiles.add(namepath);`

Answer (score 1):

I would use a JList. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Lists](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html) for more information and examples.

The example is almost exactly what you want. It shows you how to dynamically add a String to the `ListModel` of the JList.